# How to insert data into GCP Datastore which is in different project in VM instance?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

Hi I am new to GCP and python, I have one requirement:
I have 2 projects project_1 and project_2, I am running python code in project_1's VM instance and want to insert data into project_2's Datastore. I dont know how to set project_2 in the python code.
If there is any code which sends data to different project's datastore that would be helpful.
I am using this code and it is inserting data into project_1's datastore.
Please help me out.
Thanks in advance

```
from google.cloud import datastore
# Create, populate and persist an entity with keyID=1234
client = datastore.Client()
key = client.key('EntityKind', 1234)
entity = datastore.Entity(key=key)
entity.update({
    'foo': u'bar',
    'baz': 1337,
    'qux': False,
})
client.put(entity)
# Then get by key for this entity
result = client.get(key)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question would benefit from showing some in finding the solution.

A Google search for "[`datastore.Client`](https://googleapis.dev/python/datastore/latest/client.html)", returns the API documentation for the wrapper describing the parameters:

```
project (str) – (Optional) The project to pass to proxied API methods.
credentials (Credentials) – (Optional) The OAuth2 Credentials to use for this client.
```

You will want to specify the other project using the `project` argument.

You will need to ensure that the Service Account that you're using (probably the Compute Engine default Service Account but you should consider creating a specific Service Account for your code), includes appropriate [IAM roles](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/access/iam#iam_roles)|permissions to read|write to Datastore, perhaps `roles/datastore.user`.

See [this](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python) tutorial for getting started with the Cloud Client Libraries for Datastore using Python.

Comment: Thanks you so much for your inputs, datastore.Client(project=my-project) helped me..!!!!